# Блокируется часть контента страницы в браузерах

Tags: javascript, html, https

Браузеры блокируют скрипт `slick`-слайдера. Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Имеет смысл описать что помогло, что бы Юрий добавил это как ответ и пометить, что проблема решена (для потомков).

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По видимому, проблема произошла из-за того, что ваш сайт работает по `https`, однако часть ресурсов передается по незащищенному протоколу `http`. Дабы не дублировать довольно обширную тему, оставлю [ссылку на расширенную статью](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Security/MixedContent/FixMixedContent).

Если вкратце, то исправить это поведение можно или явно указывая протокол:

```
<script src="https://example.com/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Или вовсе его не указывая:

```
<script src="//example.com/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Именно так. У меня путь к jquery был через http, сменил на https и все заработало.